# Is it possible to remove class of an element when change the screen size?

Tags: css, class, media, screen-size

I'm working on a menu bar @ which initially which have a width property and when the screen size is less than 767(`@media screen and (max-width:767px)`) I need to remove that property.so I'm trying to implement that using a class.the height property is specified in this class and want to remove that class when width is less than `767px` .Is it possible to remove class of an element when change the screen size?.

Comment: this is possible using javascript

Comment: @ron can you please explore it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need javascript if you only want to change the properties.

Write the styling of that class inside a media query e.g

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
// i am usign MIN-WIDTH:786px not MAX-WIDTH
.yourclass{
float: right;
}
}
```

So this property will be added to that element ONLY on screens greater than 786.

Comment: Select it as the answer if its what you are looking for :)

Comment: i am using min-width instead of max-width so the property will automatically be removed on <767px :)

Answer (score 2):

basically this will remove the class `blue` when `window width <= 767`. this is `jquery` btw

```
$(window).resize(function(){

      if($(window).width() <= 767){
        $('.blue').removeClass('blue');
      }
    });
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p35oLu1j/)

Comment: but this is not js ,is it jquery?

Comment: jquery is javascript its just jquery is a library

Comment: yeah i know,but i doesn't using jQuery library in my project

Comment: But, the issue with the width() function is that it doesn’t return the correct value of the window as it takes into effect things like body padding and scroll bars on the window. so using width() function is not at all reliable

Answer (score 1):

```js
alert($(window).width());

if($(window).width() > 500) {
        $('#body').addClass('limit1200');
        $('#body').removeClass('limit400');
    }else{
        $('#body').addClass('limit400');
        $('#body').removeClass('limit1200');
    }
```

```css
.limit400 h1 { font-size:10px; }
.limit1200 h1 { font-size:50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body" class="limit400">
    <h1>Hey :D</h1>
</div>
```